# Can't figure out how to extract multiple doubles from a string and store them in a array of double

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm still new to C (and programming in general) so I'm trying to practice some of C concepts before some upcoming assignment.

I'm trying to write a simple program that takes all input from the keyboard but only stores doubles.

I also want my program to end if I type **'END'** or if it reaches **EOF** (in case I feel like implementing file inputs in the future).

I'm trying to become more familiar with dynamic arrays so I chose to store all keyboard input in a dynamic string first and then the plan is to extract doubles from said string and store them in a dynamic array of doubles.

My current issue is that I can't figure out how to isolate each double within the string while ignoring the other characters. So far, I've tried using `scanf()`, `sscanf()` and `strtod()`. I've read the official documentation but with my limited understanding I can't get them to do what I want.

My plan was to use a blank space as a delimiter to separate each double value. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to "move forward" within the string and thus each index of my double array ends up getting filled up with the same double value, which is always the first one in the String.

**I left some of my previous failed attempts in the code below for better context:**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//Function handles the logic for figuring out if 'END' was typed in.
bool ifEnd(char* userString, size_t counter) {
    bool userEnd = false;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < counter; index++)
    {
        if ((userString[index - 2] == 'E' && userString[index - 1] == 'N' && userString[index] == 'D')) {
            userEnd = true;
        }
        else if ((userString[index - 3] == 'Q' && userString[index - 2] == 'U' && userString[index - 1] == 'I' && userString[index] == 'T')) {
            userEnd = true;
        }
    }
    return userEnd;
}

int main()
{   size_t size = 10;
    size_t latestIndex = 0;
    char* string = malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    char* dummyP = string;

    string[0] = toupper(getchar());
    for (size_t index = 0; (string[index] != EOF) && (ifEnd(string, index) == false);) {
        //Replacing newline characters with a blank space
        if (string[index] == '\n')
            string[index] = ' ';

        if (index == (size - 2))
        {
            if ((dummyP = realloc(string, (size *= 2) * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
            {
                printf("No memory available, see ya!");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            else {
                string = dummyP;
                dummyP = NULL;
            }
        }
        ++latestIndex;
        ++index;
        string[index] = toupper(getchar());
    }

    //Getting rid of EOF and placing a '\0' at the end of the String.
    if(string[latestIndex] == EOF)
        string[latestIndex] = '\0';
    else
        string[latestIndex+1] = '\0';

    double* p = NULL;
    size = 10;
    double* doubleArray = malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    for (size_t index = 0; string[index] != '\0'; index++) { 
        
        if (index == (size - 2))
        {
            if ((dummyP = realloc(doubleArray, (size *= 2)*sizeof(double))) == NULL)
            {
                printf("No memory available, see ya!");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            else {
                doubleArray = dummyP;
                dummyP = NULL;
            }
        }

        //In one of my failed attempts (see my commented out code below), I tried following 
        //an example I found in `strtod`'s documentation where you can "juggle" two pointers 
        //to keep track of your place in the string. It started giving me memory violation 
        // and breaking point issues

        /*if (index % 2 == 0) {
            doubleArray[index] = strtod(string, &p);
            printf("\n%lf --i- ", doubleArray[index]);
        }
        else if (index % 2 == 1) {
            doubleArray[index] = strtod(p, &string);
            printf("\n%lf --p- ", doubleArray[index]);
        }
        else
            printf("\n||||This shouldn't happen||||\n");
        printf("%lf", *p);*/


//More failed attempts (strings below have a limit for ease of 
 //coding but I would've changed them to be dynamic if the method 
//below had work)
         /* char temp [100] = {'0'};
       sscanf(string, "%s", &temp);
       //doubleArray[index] = strtod(temp, NULL);
        printf("\n%lf --- ", doubleArray[index]);*/

       /* double temp [100] = {'0'};
       sscanf(string, "%lf", &doubleArray[index]);/*
       
       /*doubleArray[index] = strtod(temp, NULL);
        printf("\n%lf --- ", doubleArray[index]);*/

     /*doubleArray[index] = strtod(sscanf(string, %s, temp),NULL);*/

    doubleArray[index] = strtod(string, NULL);
    printf("\n%lf --- ", doubleArray[index]);

    }
    //printf("%s", string);

    free(string);
    //free(p);
    free(doubleArray);
}
```

Any help, suggestions or advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you need to detect the string `"END"` why not input with `fgets()` and save a lot of trouble building one yourself? Is everything in a single input line/string? Another way would be to input with `scanf()` and `%s` which won't care whether it's all on one line, or one line each.

Comment: @WeatherVane From reading the documentation, I was under the impression that `fgets()` only works with files.

Comment: It works with streams, and `STDIN` is a stream.

Comment: Simple way: `char str[100]; while(scanf("%99s", str) == 1) { if(stricmp(str, "END") == 0) break; /* etc */ }` or strcasecmp() whatever you have.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, I'll look into it then. And yes, all keyboard input gets stored in a single dynamic string. My first implementation used `scanf()` which was kind of nice because with `%*s` I had the option to just ignore wrong characters. But the problem is that scanf() "ate" my characters 'n', 'e' and 'i'. Apparently, because scanf() with %lf also takes in scientific notation.

Comment: Just read strings, and then process each string with `sscanf()` or `strtod()` to extract the `double` values. It is usually easier to process a string than to work directly with the input stream.

Answer (score 2):

> to extract multiple doubles from a string and store them in a array of double

1. Parse the string to find the number of `double`.  Use `strtod()`.
2. Form the array.
3. Parse the string again and save the values.

---

Use the end pointer from `strtod()` know when to begin parsing for the next double.

```
// Return count of successfully parsed double.
// Return -1 if non-double detected
int string_to_doubles(double *d, const char *src) {
  int count = 0;
  while (*src) {
    char *endptr;
    double x = strtod(src, &endptr);
    if (src == endptr) {
      return -1;  // Non-numeric text.
    }
    src = (const char *) endptr; 
    count++;
    if (d) {
      *d++ = x;  // Saved parsed value
    }
    // Consume trailing white-space.
    while (isspace(*(unsigned char *)src)) {
      src++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Usage

```
int SL_parse(const char *s) {
  int count = string_to_doubles(NULL, s);
  if (count <= 0) {
    return count;
  }
  
  // to use an "array"
  double array_of_double[count];
  string_to_doubles(array_of_double, s);
  // ....
  
  // to use dynamic memory
  double *pointer_to_doubles = malloc(sizeof pointer_to_doubles[0] * count);
  if (pointer_to_doubles) {
    string_to_doubles(pointer_to_doubles, s);
    // ....
    free(pointer_to_doubles);
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: You could emphasize that option "array" uses the now optional variable array construct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like this approach, although  I can't figure out the use for the block  **if (src == endptr) {**
   **return -1;  // Non-numeric text.
   }** I understand it identifies if a non numeric value is found but where is the -1 stored or used?

Comment: @SarcasticLeo `int count = string_to_doubles(NULL, s);` saves that -1 in `count`.  It is used in `if (count <= 0) {`.